# Does Azure Static WebSite support HostName mapping with https

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-cdn

I am able to setup a static website using azure storage -> static website and map to a container blob. I used the link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

I want to know if its possible to map it to a https custom domain name ?

I was following the below link but i am bit confused if it needs CDN to do https custom host name mapping. If it requires CDN then i can remove static website hosting because CDN also does hosting which is same as Static WebSite?

Are there any security related features that change between Azure Static WebSite and CDN hosting? Our website doesnt have video content and its not open to global makrets just a country.

So  my main question is, is Azure Static WebSite hosting enough and does it allow host name mapping with https?

https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip138.html

Comment: It looks like you need a CDN (see your own link): "*To enable HTTPS, you'll have to use Azure CDN because Azure Storage does not yet natively support HTTPS with custom domains.*". CDN does not host, you have to configure endpoints that it pulls from.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Static WebSite hosting is not enough to map with https, but it allow host name mapping with https by Azure CDN.

The document you are following described very clear about how to do that, and there is nothing to worry about the security after you enable https and set the certificate. Actually, Azure CDN support certificate management.[image]
[image]

REST API in Postman
[image]

Comment: Can this website be able to call rest apis ?

Comment: Yes, this website can call rest api.@FullStackBrain